# issue with @types/jquery upgrading from 2.0.47 to 3.2.11

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, typescript, definitelytyped

Been using @types/jquery 2.0.47 for a while now w/out any issues.  I've tried to upgrade to 3.2.11, and now nothing compiles at all when i build my visual studio solution.  I'm getting tons of errors, not all the same, but definitely related.  I am using typescript 2.4. For example:

**Build:Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'.**

```
if ($("#txtSelPrj") && $("#txtSelPrj").val().length > 0) ...
```

**Build:Property 'startsWith' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'**

```
var cityVal = $("#City").val();
if (cityVal.startsWith('MyCity')) ...
```

and so on.  Below is my tsconfig.json .  Is there something I'm missing on why this is happening?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": "./scripts",
    "declaration": false,
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "scripthost",
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2015.iterable"
    ],
    "types": [
      "angular-ui-bootstrap",
      "angular",
      "autolinker",
      "bootbox",
      "bootstrap-notify",
      "bootstrap",
      "bootstrap-switch",
      "cldrjs",
      "globalize",
      "googlemaps",
      "google.analytics",
      "imagesloaded",
      "jquery.blockui",
      "jquery.bootstrap.wizard",
      "jquery",
      "jqueryui",
      "jquery.validation",
      "jsts",
      "kendo-ui",
      "masonry-layout",
      "qtip2",
      "signalr",
      "urijs",
      "moment"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "build"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "node_modules/moment"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true,
    "useCache": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs : http://api.jquery.com/val/ JQuery 3 definitely returns `number` from a call to `val()` as shown below:

[image]

So the current @types/jquery for `v3` is an accurate reflection of the docs. Thus the error:

> Build:Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'.

Is definitely **correct** as `length` does not exist on `number`.

## Fix

You can either do a type guard to ensure its a string e.g. `typeof` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Or if you are lazy (and like playing with ) use a type assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: I guess that's it then.  i honestly didn't expect an upgrade like this would break my entire application, but I guess i'll have to go into this one more slowly.  Thx.